# using spline and splint

Tags: fortran, fortran90

for using spline and splint subroutine in fortran, in the subroutine there are first derivatives and second derivatives of array. but here I have just yi=f(xi), for the derivatives which quantity should I put in the subroutine?

Comment: Could you share some code to give us a better idea of how to help you?

Comment: You have provided far too little context and explanation for anyone to provide help.

Comment: I use subroutine in the Numerical recipes for fortran 77 &  90. I mean this subroutine in this book SUBROUTINE spline(x,y,n,yp1,ypn,y2) and SUBROUTINE splint(xa,ya,y2a,n,x,y). I have just numerical quantity for yi and xi but for first derivatives and second derivatives I don't know what should i do

Comment: In order to determine a spline, you need more than x/y values. You need additionally some boundary conditions on the both ends. Either first derivatives, or vanishing second derivatives (natural splines) or periodic boundary conditions (periodic splines). Anyway, numerical recipes tells you, that by setting the derivatives at the ends to values > 1e30, you will get natural splines from those routines with vanishing second derivatives.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're still interested in a solution, but to help anyone who has the same problem:

The books 'numerical recipes for fortran 77" (and 90) give quite clear explanation of what these subroutines do.
You have to call SPLINE first and it will calculate the second derivatives.
Then you call SPLINT where you put in your values as well as the derivatives.

You can use first derivatives as boundary conditions.